# how to measure number of log events filebeat has consumed and logstash has processed

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have an ELK stack as follows: 
 FileBeat --> Redis --> Logstash --> ES --> Kibana.

I am using the [metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html) plugin in Logstash but I am not able to make any sense out of it.

How can I measure the number of events read from logs and sent to redis by filebeat and number of events processed by logstash at a given point in time?

```
input
     generator {
        type => "generated"
      }
filter

     metrics {
        meter => "events"
        add_tag => "metric"
      }
output

    if "metric" in [tags] {
        stdout {
          codec => line {
            format => "rate: %{[events][rate_5m]}"
          }
        }
      }
```

I can see output as

> rate: some number

Comment: Theres also timelion in kibana which shows you the number of logs reaching elastic search. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html#_literal_meter_literal_values) explains the number you are seeing.

> "[thing][rate_5m]" - the per-second event rate in a 5-minute sliding window

So the number you are seeing are the number of event per second over the last 5 minutes.

But the solution is not very far from what you had: you'll have to use the `[events][count]`, in the same way as `[events][rate_5m]`. This will give you the number of events for the last 5 minutes (this can be changed with the `flush_interval` setting)

Comment: so does the above figure tells me whether that many log messages had hit logstash per second? and what needs to be done get same metrics for filebeat? I tried looking for some filebeat plugins but nothings there over internet

Comment: @MrunalGosar `[events][rate_5m]` give you an average number of hits per second for the last 5 minutes, calculated with number of messages in the last 5 minutes / (60 * 5).

Comment: @MrunalGosar for filebeat, I don't know, but unless you are dealing with multiline log messages, the number of messages from logstash should be the same order of magnitude

Comment: One last favor..would you be able to tell me what needs to be done to capture events perday..I tried looking through the docs but nothing tells me that there is some provision to get events per day

Comment: @MrunalGosar To know the number of event per day, you can use a) one index per day and check the number of document, b) use an elasticsearch request, c) use the metrics plugin and `[events][count]`, write the result somewhere and do the calculation

Comment: @MrunalGosar And with one index per day, it is very easy to delete data based on the date (and it's even easier with [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about.html)